# Resize a Jtable to fill the JFrame and still scroll

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtable

I am trying to resize two JTable that are in scrollPanels that are in a Tab view.  I have managed to set the size of the frame to 12000, 5000 but the Jtable/scrollPanel are not playing ball.

I found some code to set the size of the columns of the table that worked BUT instead of filling the Jframe it just added a scroll bar at the bottom of the table/scrollPanel

can anyone come up with a way of getting the table to fill the frame and still have scrolling?

The Table File is:

```
public class ViewInTablePET extends JPanel {
private String[][] rowData = new String[0][];
private String columnNames[] = {"Shop", "Type", "price", "dateAcquired", "notes"};
private DefaultTableModel tableMod = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
private JTable table = new JTable(tableMod);

public ViewInTablePET() {

    String bob;
    String[] dan;

    for (Integer i = 0; i < AppModel.getArrayListPet().size(); i++) { 
        bob = AppModel.getArrayListPet().get(i).toString();
        dan = AppModel.getStringAsArray(bob, "\t");
        tableMod.insertRow(i, new Object[]{dan[0], dan[1], dan[2], dan[3], dan[4]});
    }
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);    
}
}
```

The Fram file is:

```
public class ViewInTabbs extends JFrame {

JLabel Average = new JLabel("Click a table row to get the average price");

public ViewInTabbs() {

    JTabbedPane tabs =              new JTabbedPane();
    ViewInTablePetShope petShop =   new ViewInTablePetShope();
    ViewInTablePET pet =            new ViewInTablePET();

    tabs.add("Pet Shope", (JPanel) petShop);
    tabs.add("Pets in the shop", (JPanel) pet);
    this.setTitle("Tabb View of Data");
    this.add(tabs, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setSize(12000, 5000);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.add(Average, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
public void setAverage(String ave) {
    this.Average.setText(ave);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ahh .. on second reading: the culprit is the LayoutManager of ViewInTablePET which defaults to FlowLayout. Change to BorderLayout

```
 public ViewInTablePET() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    // your code
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `ViewInTablePET` class you add the `JScrollPane` with the constrains `BorderLayout.CENTER`, but I do not see the `setLayout( new BorderLayout() )` call in that class. Since a `JPanel` by default has a `FlowLayout` this will not have the desired effect. It should however work when you set the layout to `BorderLayout` first